# "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside of the array." exception occured

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I encountered this exception while setting the SetKeyName method of ImageCollection of ImageList.

```
 this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
        this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;
        this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
        this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(1, "");
```

i have used this "imageList1.ImageStream" in my Main Form too, and it works fine there. I am stuck here and i do not know what actually this issue is, how it raised and how can i solve this.

Any suggestions and comments will be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure the resource is available to your class?  All this error means is that you are trying to set a key name to a value that doesnt exist.  Clearly, your `imageList1` is not being found.

Comment: Ensure if you have 2 images in the ImageList before calling SetKeyName()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;

for (int i = 0; i < this.imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
    this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(i, "");
```

Comment: Logically you are true and i too agree with that. But this does not work because i am having issue already on the first statement this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));  Exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.InvalidOperationException: Loading of the ImageList did not succeed.

Comment: @user2991876 OK. This error is a separate question. If you open a new question, we would be happy to help you to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this line :

```
this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(1, "");
```

Is causing your exception. Of course it could also be the first line with Index 0. Basically the exception is saying that code failed while trying to access the array at a given index. The reason being that the array doesn't have an item at that index.

For example in your case the code assumes that there are 2 items in the array. One at index 0 and one at index 1. If the array has only one item the second line will fail and throw the exception.

All you have to do is make sure you have an item at a given index before you try to perform any operations on it.

Something like :

```
if(this.imageList1.Images.Count >= 2)
{
   this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(1, "");
}
```

Comment: See @rhughes answer for a better approach to dealing with lists in general. For loops are great in cases like these.