# Set a Key on ImageList control at specific Index

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have an ImageList Control in a powershell form where I'm adding a few icons from a folder with this function:

```
function addToImagelist
{
    $ICOs = Get-ChildItem "$IconDir" | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".ico" }

    foreach ($ICO in $ICOs)
    {
        Write-Debug "$IconDir\$ICO"
        $Icon = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$IconDir\$ICO")       
        $imagelistIcons.Images.Add([String]$ICO, $Icon)
    }
}
```

It's setting the ImageKey of every icon to the filename + extension.
What I'm now trying to do is changing the ImageKey afterwards.

I tried:

```
$imagelistIcons.Images.SetKeyName(0, 'NewKey')
```

But this outputs the following error:

> ERROR: Exception calling "SetKeyName" with "2" argument(s): "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?  `$imagelistIcons.Images.Count` tells me that there are definitely items in the ImageList.

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570313/indexoutofrangeexception-index-was-outside-of-the-array-exception-occured
Thanks, Tim.

Comment: I found the problem. I had two different imagelists in the form. One was global, the other one a local one. So it was a simple scoping issue. Thanks @TimHaintz

Comment: Thanks for letting us know @StUffz.